# Using recursion in java for a palindrome question on leetcode

Tags: java, recursion, palindrome

I debugger code shown below, and every thing looks find until "returns true". It does not return immediately, instead it went back somehow. However, I do not assign value when I call the method itself.

I think if I try to use while, it would be much simpler after I finish the recursion.

Could anyone please help me figure out the bug?

Thanks in advance!

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        return isPalindromeHelper(s, 0, s.length() - 1);
    }
    public boolean isPalindromeHelper(String s, int first,int last) {
        if(first >= last) {
            return true;
        } else {
            char chead = s.charAt(first);
            char ctail = s.charAt(last);
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(chead) || !Character.isLetterOrDigit(ctail)) {
                if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(chead)) {
                    first++;
                }
                if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ctail)) {
                    last--;
                }
                isPalindromeHelper(s, first, last); 
            } 
            else if(chead != ctail) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        first++;
        last--;
        return isPalindromeHelper(s, first, last);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your code. It appears to work fine. You may want to
change the following to include a return on the method call.

```
              if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ctail)) {
                    last--;
                }
              return isPalindromeHelper(s, first, last);  // <- added return
```

If you can explain where you think any problem is I will try to help.

Comment: before adding the return, if I try "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama", it appeared to be false. However, after I added "return" it works somehow.